# Como alterar o final de um nome

Tags: php, regex

Como alterar o final de um nome
por exemplo

WELITON, MAICON, WELIGTON

para

WELITOM, MAICOM, WELIGTOM

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pode usar o preg_replace, veja um exemplo:

**Criei uma função para retornar o nome alterado:**

```
function alteraFinal($nome){
    $pattern = ['/ON\b/'];
    $replace = ['OM'];
    return preg_replace($pattern,$replace, $nome);
}
```

Ou se preferir, uma versão com código reduzido:

```
function alteraFinal($nome){
    return preg_replace('/ON\b/i','OM', $nome);
}
```

**Utilização:**

```
echo alteraFinal('WELITON');
echo '<br/>';
echo alteraFinal('MAICON');
echo '<br/>';
echo alteraFinal('WELIGTON');
echo '<br/>';
echo alteraFinal('CONRRADO');
```

**Resultado:**

> WELITOM
>
> MAICOM
>
> WELIGTOM
>
> CONRRADO

Espero ter ajudado!

Answer (score 2):

Depois que criar o padrão regex, use a função preg_replace para fazer a substituição. Deve ser passando como parâmetro o padrão para encontrar os caracteres que deseja substituir, os novos caracteres e o texto que será alterado.
http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.preg-replace.php

Answer (score 1):

Bom cara, com o `regex`, compensa mais fazer aquele esqueminha do `\w*`, assim você pode digitar qualquer caractere quantas vezes quiser, se for apenas nome `[a-zA-Z]`
mas se for especificamente o final do nome, coloque `[a-zA-Z]*(com|con)` <-- esses no caso de Maicon e Wellington

Comment: essa parte eu ja tinha entendido mas eu quero que nao encontre as palavras com ton|con no meio por exemplo conteudo ou tesCONtes

Comment: como assim encontrar no meio ?

Comment: Dessa forma encontra também as palavras com "CON|TON" no meio dela, eu quero encontrar somente quando o "CON|TON" for no final

Comment: tenta o [con|ton]{1} assim ele terá que ter um dos dois no final

Answer (score 1):

consegui assim

```
    $nomeLimpo = preg_replace('/CON\b/','COM', $nomeLimpo);
    $nomeLimpo = preg_replace('/TON\b/','TOM', $nomeLimpo);
```

Answer (score 0):

Exemplo com [str_ireplace()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-ireplace.php)

```
$str = 'あTON, いCON, うTON';
echo str_ireplace(array('con,', 'ton,'), array('com', 'tom'), $str.',');
```

nota: Funcionará caso a string original possua sempre o mesmo padrão sem espaçamento antes do caractere separator. No seu caso, vírgula.

Também pode optar por [str_replace()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php). A diferença é que `str_ireplace()` é case-insensitive, ou seja, ignora letra minúscula e maiúscula.